# Problems with placing divs and responsive design for mobile devices, could you check my code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Beginner in a real fix, help needed!**

Hello, I'm a beginner with html and css, and I don't have any friends to ask help from, so I decided to try and ask from here. I'm making a simple website for my open university course, that needs to be finished in a week.

a) I'm having real trouble with getting two divs in the footer next to each other, I followed MiMo Learn to Code-app's tutorial for making the footer and have the code written the same way as the tutorial told me to do it, but the divs just don't go next to each other no matter what I do. So the problem lies 
somewhere in the footer>container>column-part.

b) My navigation bar doesn't look good when checking it with a phone. It looks nice on pc/laptop web browser, but on mobile device the header's navigation links don't stay in the header, like, the navigation links go over the header border to the content part... It's really difficult to explain this, my native language isn't english either so... Like, the navigation links don't stretch on the same row when on mobile device, the navigation links go under each other. The row doesn't shrink in one piece!

Could I share my code for someone wiser to check? I'd be so grateful if this problem gets solved because I'm in a quite a hurry.

```css
    body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    }
    
    @viewport {
    width: auto;
    zoom: 1.0;
    }
    
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif
    color: #333;
    }
    
    h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-variant: small-caps
    }
    
    h2 {
    font-size: 1.50em;
    font-variant: small-caps
    }
    
    #header ul {
    margin:0;
    padding;0;
    } 
    
    #header li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 73px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    }
    
    #header li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white
    }
    
    #header li:Hover {
    background-color:#2f2f2f85;
    }
    
    .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    }
    
    #content h3 {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    }
    
    #header {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    height: 75px;
    }
    
    p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    a {
    color: #1abc9c;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    a:hover {
    color: #F6A623
    }
    
    #header a {
        color:white;
    }
    
    .content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    }
    
    #footer h4 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
    
    #footer p {
    color: white;
    }
    
    #footer {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    padding: 50px 0;
    }
    
    .column {
    min-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;   
    }
```

```html
        
    <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="mylogo" style="float:left;width:70px;height:70px;"></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="link5.html">link 5</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
                
    <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
    <h3 class="otsikko">Title</h3>
    <div class="teksti">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
                    
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
    <h4>Title: Social medias</h4>
    <p>
    <img src="twitterlogo.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink1">Twitter</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink2">Instagram</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="linkedinlogo.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink3">LinkedIn</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="fblogo.png" alt="Facebook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink4">Facebook</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="column">
    <h4>Title: My Story</h4>
    <p>Text: short introduction</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And here's how to website looks on my pc browser now, (you can see here the A. problem, how the divs on footer (löydät minut & tarinani (in the code, social medias & my story) don't go next to each other, I can attach a pic of the B. problem too if needed.):
[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5ZT2.png)

I'd be forever happy if somebody could help a simpleton like me.

[PIC OF THE NAVIGATION BAR ON MOBILE DEVICES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI9aT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the footer is that the second column has the `id="column"` instead of `class="column"`

For header part you have set a fixed height equal to 75px for header. If you set `min-height:75px;` it can grows to fit content. Also as you have set float for `li` items, you have to clear the floating effect by a clear div like `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after `li` items. Also do not forget to close `</ul>`

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    }
    
    @viewport {
    width: auto;
    zoom: 1.0;
    }
    
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif
    color: #333;
    }
    
    h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-variant: small-caps
    }
    
    h2 {
    font-size: 1.50em;
    font-variant: small-caps
    }
    
    #header ul {
    margin:0;
    padding;0;
    } 
    
    #header li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 73px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    }
    
    #header li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white
    }
    
    #header li:Hover {
    background-color:#2f2f2f85;
    }
    
    .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    }
    
    #content h3 {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    }
    
    #header {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    min-height: 75px;
    }
    
    p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    a {
    color: #1abc9c;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    a:hover {
    color: #F6A623
    }
    
    #header a {
        color:white;
    }
    
    .content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
    }
    
    #footer h4 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
    
    #footer p {
    color: white;
    }
    
    #footer {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    padding: 50px 0;
    }
    
    .column {
    min-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;   
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="mylogo" style="float:left;width:70px;height:70px;"></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="link5.html">link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
                
    <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
    <h3 class="otsikko">Title</h3>
    <div class="teksti">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
                    
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
    <h4>Title: Social medias</h4>
    <p>
    <img src="twitterlogo.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink1">Twitter</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink2">Instagram</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="linkedinlogo.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink3">LinkedIn</a>
    <br/>
    <img src="fblogo.png" alt="Facebook" style="width:25px;height:25px;"><a href="socialmedialink4">Facebook</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
    <h4>Title: My Story</h4>
    <p>Text: short introduction</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was being sloppy there with the class- and id-tags... But the text on the navigation bar still goes over the header, even if I changed it to min-height: 75px; and added <div style="clear:both"></div> after li items. I'll add a pic to my original message of the situation with the navigation bar on mobile devices.

Comment: have you closed `</ul>` before clear div? @cinnacode

Comment: I tried placing </ul> before and after clear div, but it makes no difference. The website is still unresponsive when checked on mobile device or minimizing the browser window... :/

Comment: Can you check the code snippet I sent with mobile? @cinnacode

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do that. I don't have an web address for the website yet, it's only on my computer and when visiting stack overflow-site on mobile, it doesn't let check (run) code snippets.